# Levenberg–Marquardt (LMA) implementation in Java (to replace Python scipy.optimise.leastsq)

Tags: java, matrix, scipy, least-squares, levenberg-marquardt

Please could someone suggest a good implementation of the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm in Java? I prefer completeness and accuracy over performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/estimation/LevenbergMarquardtEstimator.html. Never tried this particular class myself, but apache commns is really good.